# im using redis with docker-compose and socket-io and i get undefined value after setting to redis

Tags: sockets, docker-compose, redis, undefined

[[My example code looks like this and its perfecly working fine on localhost i started redis server with docker run -p 6379:6379 -it redis/redis-stack-server:latest command
but when i start redis server using docker-compose file i get no error on set command but im getting undefined value on get command why

docker-compose.yml file is like this
version: '3'
services:
nginx:
image: 127.0.0.1:5000/socketmw_nginx
build: ./nginx
links:
- socketio-1
- socketio-2
- socketio-3
- socketio-4
ports:
- '88:88'
restart: always

socketio-1:
image: 127.0.0.1:5000/socketmw_s1
build: ./service
links:
- redis-adapter
- redis-cache-db
environment:
- NAME=socketio-1
restart: always
depends_on:
- redis-adapter
- redis-cache-db

socketio-2:
image: 127.0.0.1:5000/socketmw_s2
build: ./service
links:
- redis-adapter
- redis-cache-db
environment:
- NAME=socketio-2
restart: always
depends_on:
- redis-adapter
- redis-cache-db

socketio-3:
image: 127.0.0.1:5000/socketmw_s3
build: ./service
links:
- redis-adapter
- redis-cache-db
environment:
- NAME=socketio-3
restart: always
depends_on:
- redis-adapter
- redis-cache-db

socketio-4:
image: 127.0.0.1:5000/socketmw_s4
build: ./service
links:
- redis-adapter
- redis-cache-db
environment:
- NAME=socketio-4
restart: always
depends_on:
- redis-adapter
- redis-cache-db

redis-adapter:
image: redis:alpine
restart: always

redis-cache-db:
image: 'redis:7.2.3'
ports:
- '6380:6380'
command: redis-server --save 10 1 --appendonly yes --port 6380

Answer (score 0):

```
`my node js code is like this 
const redis_client = await createClient({
  url: `redis://${config.redis_db.redis_db_addr}:${config.redis_db.redis_db_port}`,
  legacyMode: true,
}).on('error', (err) => console.log('Redis Client Error', err)).connect();

await redis_client.set('sda', 'vasdsadsadsadaaalue');
const value = await redis_client.get('sda');
console.log(' ~ file: index.js:9 ~ value:', value);
]
```